# vector assign/insert and casting value to be assigned/inserted

Tags: c++, vector

I have two vectors:

```
std::vector<Foo> original;
std::vector<Foo *> pointers;
```

Currently, I am going over `original` and using `push_back` to copy the values from it to `pointers`.

e.g. something like this:

```
pointers.push_back(&(*original.at(0));
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this using vector's `assign` or `insert` methods?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: That's a bad idea to begin with if `original` ever changes size.  The contents of a `std::vector` are not guaranteed to remain at the same addresses.

Comment: I know :(. I can't change it so right now I have to run this every time it changes. But do you know of any ways?

Comment: Maybe explain your rationale for wanting this ... where would you use the original vector, and where do you want to use the vector of pointers?

Comment: You can use a custom iterator to do it, but a simple for loop will be so much less code.

Comment: It appears that the pointers vector is supposed to be given to some threads to run a job over the original vector.

Comment: Any reason the threads cannot be given a pointer or reference to the original vector, at least?

Comment: That might be a good idea. I'd rather that this use indexes rather than the pointers vector though. I'll see if I can change it after all. Thanks

Comment: Indices are slightly better, but still require you to update the vector of indices whenever the original vector changes (particularly if there are some deletions from the original one).

Comment: Also since you're working with threads, make sure you have some synchronization mechanism. STL containers are generally not thread-safe.

Comment: I will, thanks for all the advice everyone.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

There are a number of reasons why what you're doing is ultimately going to result in a segfault or something similarly bad. Mainly, your vector of pointers is pointing at the **addresses** of the elements in your original vector. When you push back to the original vector, the elements may get moved elsewhere and the addresses are no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to throw boost library into the mix, this can be done quite tersely (using [boost::transform_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html)):

```
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>
#include <memory> // for addressof

struct Foo {};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> original;
    std::vector<Foo*> pointers;

    pointers.assign(
        boost::make_transform_iterator(original.begin(), std::addressof<Foo>),
        boost::make_transform_iterator(original.end(), std::addressof<Foo>));
}
```

And given the fact that vector elements are stored contiguosly, you could also use
[counting iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html):

```
pointers.assign(
    boost::make_counting_iterator(original.data()),
    boost::make_counting_iterator(original.data() + original.size()));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please correct me if I am wrong**, but aren't all the members in `vector` in consecutive memory?

I believe that you could use the [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) method, you only have to figure out how to add the `sizeof(Foo)` into every inserted pointer.

Comment: The members in `vector` are in fact stored sequentially in memory. *But* the location of the whole storage can change after another `vector` operation (e.g. after an `insert()` or `reserve()`). And no, the operation described in the question cannot be accomplished elegantly with a single `insert`.